# fatal error in gc collecting from unknown thread

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, garbage-collection

I'm using Microsoft-IIS/10.0, AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2, AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319, to run my application. the issue happened when I'm calling a function from unmanaged dll (C code). Everything works well for 3 or max 5 runnings. After that the "fatal error" occurs and the application stop. Any help will be wellcomed. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using unmanaged resources you have to free them, or if already freed then don't try and free them again. Some code would help greatly here, but it sounds like you are hitting a null pointer in your finalise method or something, and then the garbage collector is trying to dispose of the object with a null pointer being referenced.

For example

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);
public class ExampleClass
{
   private int _hwnd;
   private IntPtr _dc;   
   public ExampleClass(int hwnd) : IDispose
   {
      this._dc = GetDC(hWnd);
      this._hwnd = hwnd;
      Console.WriteLine("Got pointer to device context of window with hWnd" + hwnd.toString());
   } 

   public void Dispose(){
      ReleaseDc(this._hwnd, this._ds);
   }

   ~ExampleClass()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Finalizing object");
      ReleaseDc(this._hwnd, this._ds); //Bang, the handle was already released in the dispose method....
   }
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your response. I'm using the "using (...)" command for the unmanaged ressource.

Comment: Indeed you are. This doesn't however mean that is the end of the story. See the above code, if you were using the using(...) command all this means is that the Dispose method is called automatically. That's it. That's all it does. Now if the Dispose method deallocates the memory referenced by the pointer, and then you try and re-release it in the finalise method, which is called by the GC at any point in the future, then boooooooom....

Comment: I'm greatfull for your input. I think I found the error. I was calling the free method of the kernel dll instead of the unmanaged ressource. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my code:

public class FmuInstance : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string fileName;
    private IntPtr wrapper;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FreeLibrary(IntPtr library);


    public void LoadDLL(string path)
    {
        wrapper = LoadLibrary(path);
        if (wrapper == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new DllNotFoundException("----");
        FreeLibrary(wrapper);
    }

    public void FreeDLL()
    {
        FreeLibrary(wrapper);
    }

    public void FreeInstance()
    {
        if (wrapper != IntPtr.Zero)
            FreeDLL();
        wrapper = IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free managed resources
            }
            // Free unmanaged resources
            FreeInstance();
            // Avoid disposing multiple times
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is my unmanaged ressource. Still not working. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your if statement will never fire in the Dispose method, as disposedValue is never set, and further more is not declared outside of the method scope, ie at class level. Effectively your FreeInstance() method is never called. Put a debug statement in it and see! :-)